# Custom drawRect: parameter

Tags: ios, drawrect

Is there any way to add a second parameter in a custom UIView class in the drawRect method?

I am currently using a UIView to draw a text string but the text itself is set in the drawRect method. Is there any way to pass in the text variable in something like

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect(NSString *)text
```

and if not are there any alternative work arounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would generally have a custom `@property` for your `UIView` subclass:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;
```

You might even have a custom setter that calls `setNeedsDisplay`, such that when you set the `text` property, the view's `drawRect` will get called, e.g.:

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    _text = [text copy];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Your `drawRect` could then reference `self.text` when it needs to reference that `NSString`.

Comment: Hi, Rob, in the setter you use _text but in drawRect you refer it as self.text, may I know why you do so? Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I should have thought of this. I used the property and then set the text in my view controller before adding the custom view as a subview.

Comment: @Unheilig The critical observation is that you should not use `self.text` to set the property in the setter, because `self.text = ...` translates to `[self setText:...]`, and you'll get infinite recursion. You should never use accessor methods (setters and getters) in the accessor methods, themselves (or in the `init` and `dealloc` methods, either). In `drawRect`, you can use the synthesized ivar, `_text`, to retrieve the value if you want (it's a matter of a personal preference), but I always use the getter where I can, as it offers the greatest flexibility with negligible overhead.

Comment: @Unheilig The [Use Accessor Methods to Make Memory Management Easier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW4) section of the _Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide_ outlines where one should and should not use the accessor methods.

Comment: @Rob Very nice explanation. Yes, that rang a bell - recursion. Thanks.